# Python to evaluate data from files in a folder

Tags: python, csv

I have multiple csv files in 1 folder and I need to evaluate the state of each channel: if the number of channel > 2, the state is 0, else, state is 1.

The output csv file should be in this format:

```
index | channel 1 | channel 2 | channel 3 | channel 4 | channel 5 | channel 6
  1   |    0      |    1      |     0     |     0     |    1      |   0 
  2   |    1      |    0      |     1     |     0     |    1      |   0
 ...
```

For now I can evaluate the state of 1 file only. Here is the example of one of my csv files:

```
CHANNEL
3
3
4
4
5
2
4
6
6
```

This is my code:

```
with open("csvfile1.csv") as f:
    lines1 = f.readlines()[1:]
    lines1 = [int(x) for x in lines1]

lines = [lines1]

state = [[0] * 38]

with open("csvfile3.csv", "w", newline = "") as f_out:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(
        f_out, fieldnames=["channel 1","channel 2","channel 3","channel 4","channel 5","channel 6"])
    writer.writeheader()
    for ci in [0]:  # each file
        for ch in range(38):  # each channel
            if lines[ci].count(ch + 1) > 1:
                state[ci][ch] = 0
            elif lines[ci].count(ch + 1) == 1:
                state[ci][ch] = 1
            else:
                state[ci][ch] = 0
                # check channel count, set state
    print(','.join(str(c) for c in state[0]) + '\n')
    f_out.write(','.join(str(c) for c in state[0]) + '\n')
```

Comment: `for ci in [0]:` confusing code for `ci=0`

Comment: `','.join(map(str, state[0]))`

Comment: your indentation is wrong